# A word that will cover both words and numbers

Tags: terminology

Is there a word that covers the meaning of both words and numbers?

Here is a sentence in English:

> Historically, the year 1500 is also often identified, somewhat arbitrarily, as marking the end of the Middle Ages and beginning of the Early Modern Era.

Now, consider the same sentence is written using the language that uses small circles (●) instead of spaces, and I want to describe such a case. How would I say it?

> To delimit [words?], these imaginary language uses small circles (●).

The word "words" in not really accurate because 1500 is actually a number.

Comment: 1500 "fifteenhundred" is a word. It is just spelled with digits instead of letters, but this is not really relevant.

Comment: Good point, thanks.

Comment: Also, wordhood is as arbitrary as your example 1500: unlike jk, I myself analyse it as fifteen hundred, ie. two words.

Comment: Typographically speaking, the definition of a word is anything delimitered by spacing; depending on whom you ask, punctuation is part of the spacing (so part of the delimiter) or the word itself. So using ‘words’ is fine.

Comment: If you mean the non-space strings of characters then given there are four words followed by punctuation which would each be treated as a unit, then I would simply call them character strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the term you are looking for is "[lexical] token", which matches meaning 3b here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/token
and is more broadly described for the specific context of programming languages here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Token